# Remove duplicates from a csv but only remove the duplicate with a unique value

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV with the following

```
"STAFF_STATUS","SFKEY","FIRST_NAME","SURNAME","E_MAIL"
"ACTV,"JON1,"JOHN","DOE","John.Doe@email.com
"LEFT","JAN1","JANE,"DOE,"Jane.Doe@email.com
"ACTV","STE1,"STEVE,"BEEV",Steve.Beev@email.com
"ACTV,"JON5",JOHN","DOE","John.Doe@email.com
```

I want to remove duplicate rows through out the csv but only remove the duplciates with "LEFT" in the STAFF_STATUS

I've used the following powershell but find it is about 70% accurate and sometimes leaves a "LEFT" duplicate in and removes the "ACTV" Duplicate

```
$csv1 = '\\Server\c$\Folder\CSVData.csv
$csv1a  = Import-Csv $csv1
$csv1b = $csv1a | Sort-Object -Property SURNAME,First_Name -unique
$csv1b | Export-Csv -Path "\\Server\c$\Folder\CSVData(2).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

If i put a third property in sort object it doesn't remove any duplicates. I've tried other methods including some attempts from CHATGPT but nothing works the above is as close as i can get but i need 100% accuracy.

Comment: It sounds like you simply want to remove all records that contain `LEFT` in `STAFF_STATUS`?

Comment: The example data appears to have many quoting  problems; either unopened fields or unclosed fields. Every data line is missing a QUOTATION MARK at the end of the line. Also, the FIRST_NAME in lines 3, 4, and 5 do not have matching quotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I infer from your `Sort-Object` command that you consider rows that share the same surname and first name to be duplicates.

If so, you can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group by shared surname and first name and remove those rows, if any, that have `LEFT` in the status column from each group:

```bash
$csv1a | 
  Group-Object -Property SURNAME,First_Name |
  ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Count -gt 1) {
      # A duplicate set, filter out the "LEFT" status rows.
      $_.Group | Where-Object STAFF_STATUS -ne LEFT
    } else {
      # Not part of a duplicate set, pass through.
      $_.Group
    } 
  } |
  Export-Csv -Path "\\Server\c$\Folder\CSVData(2).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Note:

- `if ($_.Count -gt 1)` ensures that only `LEFT` rows *with duplicates* are removed; if you also want to remove such rows if they occur *in isolation*, remove this conditional and the `else` branch or - more efficiently, since this then amounts to *unconditionally* removing `LEFT` rows - omit the `ForEach-Object` call and pipe directly to
  `Where-Object STAFF_STATUS -ne LEFT`
- Grouping by the `E_MAIL` column may be a better way to find duplicates.